# can see table matrix in preview but not in deployed report server ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I can see table matrix in preview but not  in deployed report server ssrs. I have rebuild it several times with no luck. I am using shared data base and data sets for report. Is that causing this issue? Any Solutions for this issue?

Comment: Are you using the exact same data source and dataset in dev and when deployed? if there are no rows for the dataset being returned, then SSRS may not show the table at all.

Comment: I am using same data source and data set that have millions of rows.it works fine in development but doesn't show up when in reporting server.